# Where should I store the Django media files so that I can have the same functionality as the Lynda site?

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, django-storage

I built a Django website that works like Lynda's tutorial.
Now my question is, where should I save my video files so that they are only accessible to users who are allowed to download them?
Does saving files on object space give me such a feature?
Or where should I live my website to have such a feature?
Or if I save on vps servers where my Django app is live, will it affect the speed of my app?

My ultimate goal of this question is not to share my file links

Please guide.

Comment: Just store them somewhere in the cloud or dedicated server storage and create some if and else kind of statement for a particular execution.

Comment: thank you
I completely implemented these features in my views, but when my file is saved on object spaces and the user who has access to my file, he can share the link of my files.
 Or let's say that object spaces is separate from my Django server, so the user who had access can share the links.

Comment: Yeah, Great Question he can share that. But the question is what those links are containing. If they are downloadable and usable of course someone will. But if your files are protected or just kind of media stuff which could only be played/read in the encoded format(eg.. Youtube does) in your website or application they won't be able to share it unless and until they are sharing their user id and password.

Comment: thanks again
My files are with RAR extension. But it is not protected.
So there is no solution that only users who have paid can download and not anyone else؟

Comment: If they are just files or you can say plugins or just apk which doesn't interact with the server in short offline files. They will be able to distribute it as long as they want to.

Comment: thanks alot may last Q,  If I upload the file on My Life app server, will the speed of my site slow down when downloading the file?